# Where are the console logs in an asp.net core application hosted by IIS

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, serilog

I've added logging to an asp.net core application, using the excellent Serilog library. I have added sinks for both Sql Server and Literate console.
The sql server sink works perfectly of course, but, well this is a little embarrassing, I have no clue how to display the logs in a console window.
This is what ive tried:

1. In the published directory I have run the command **dotnet run** but got an error saying that the **project.json** does not exist. This of course works if I run the command on my dev machine where that file is located. The logs are displayed the console that is opened.
2. I've also tried to run the **exe** directly, and it was saying that it is **listening on: http://localhost:5000**, but no logging was displayed in console window.

Here's the code:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        ConfigureLogging();
    }

    private void ConfigureLogging()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.LiterateConsole(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(".\\Logs\\log-{Date}.txt")
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Logging"), "Logs"/*, columnOptions: new ColumnOptions()*/)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            // If there's no available file and the request doesn't contain an extension, we're probably trying to access a page.
            // Rewrite request to use app root
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/"; // Put your Angular root page here 
                await next();
            }
        });

        loggerFactory
            .AddSerilog();

        // Ensure any buffered events are sent at shutdown
        appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(Log.CloseAndFlush);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
        app.UseMvc();



        //app.UseHangfireDashboard();             // Will be available under http://localhost:5000/hangfire
        //app.UseHangfireServer();
    }
```

How do I display the logs in the console window?

Comment: Please, show us how you're configuring your log.

Comment: Sure Fabricio I'll paste the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under IIS the console logs aren't collected. You'll need to use one of the other sinks for an IIS hosted app, such as the rolling file you've configured.

Comment: Hey a comment from the master himself :-)   
 Thanks a lot Nicholas